# Powershell WinRM (WS-manager) service is not running after enabling it in group policy

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, winrm

I need to run remote powershell commands on a 2008 R2 server, so i enabled WinRM using the group policy

[image]

but then when i go into windows services to view the running services, the Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) is not on the list

[image]

so then when i try to run powershell commands that would setup WinRM

[image]

It says that the service is not running, thus i cant register the configuration; which is what i really need since i need to run powershell commands as PS version 2 and not version 3

has anyone encountered this before? does anyone have any idea of where to start looking?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need WinRM or PowerShell remoting to run version 2.0. You just invoke powershell with that version:

```
powershell.exe -Version 2.0
```

As to your problem, I am not sure why the service is missing. Since you installed WMF 3/Powershell 3 yourself (I'm assuming, because it's 2008 R2), maybe you can try reinstalling or repairing it? Are there any messages in the event log? I admit I have never seen this before.

Have you used an installer for 2008 R2 that was customized or cut down, [like the person who asked this question](https://superuser.com/q/657623/355415)?